# For topological torus action, there is a subcircle whose fixed point is the same as the torus

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, lie-groups

Let $T=\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{S}^{1}
$ ($n$ times) be an $n$-dimensional torus acting on any topological space $X$.

The group $G$ is said to act on a space $X$ with finitely many
connective orbit types if the set $\left\{ \left[ G_{x}^{0}\right] :x\in
X\right\} $ is finite, where $G_{x}^{0}$ denotes the identity component of
the isotropy subgroup $G_{x}$ in $G$. Here $\left[ G_{x}^{0}\right]$ is the conjugacy class of $G_{x}^{0}$ in $G$.

**Lemma:** If $X$ has finitely many connective orbit type, then there is a subcircle $L=%
\mathbb{S}^{1}\subset T$ such that $X^{\mathbb{S}^{1}}=X^{T}$ (fixed point
sets of the action).

The proof is done as follows

**Proof:** Let $K_{1},K_{2},\cdots ,K_{n}$ be the connective isotropy subgroup
other than $T$. Then there is a subcircle $L\subset T$ such that $L\cap K_{i}
$ is finite for $1\leq i\leq n$. Clearly $X^{L}=X^{T}$.

I'm trying to understand the proof.

If for each
subcircle $S\subset T$, there is a $%
K_{i}$ such that $S\cap K_i$ is infinite, then $S\cap K_i$ is closed in circle $S$ and
infinite, but all closed subgroups of circle $S$ are finite or $S$ itself. So $S\cap
K_i=S$, that is $S\subset K_i$. Hence the union of all subcircles $L$ of $T$ is the subset of $K_1 \cup K_2 \cup \cdots \cup K_n$. I don't know that the union of all subcircles of $T$ is dense in $T$? And Is this used for contradiction?

I don't know how to reach the contradiction from now on. I would be very
happy if someone could explain it.

Comment: Note that it does not suffice to show that no connected isotropy subgroup intersects every circle in an infinite subgroup; you need one circle that intersects *every* connected isotropy subgroup in a finite subgroup.  But, anyway, the fact that the union of subcircles of $T$ is dense in $T$ is a purely topological (or perhaps I should say number theoretic) fact; consider a circle generated by suitably irrational angles in each torus factor.

Comment: @LSpice if the union of subcircles of $T$ is dense in $T$, then we will conclude that there is a subcirlce which intersects every connected isotropy subgroup in a finite subgroup. Moreover,  the group generated by suitably irrational angels in each torus factor is not closed. Actually the generated by suitably irrational angels in each torus factor is not circle.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461901/for-topological-torus-action-there-is-a-subcircle-whose-fixed-point-is-the-same#comment1198308_461901), I did not claim that the subgroup was closed; you asked about density.  I had taken "circle" to mean "image of a $1$-parameter subgroup", but I guess from your reply you mean literally topologically isomorphic to $S^1$ (which makes perfectly good sense—better than my interpretation, in fact).

Comment: To show that the union of circles, in the sense of topological isomorphs of $S^1$, is dense, it suffices to show that the set of finite-order elements is dense, since every such element lies on a circle.  This is implied by the density of $\mathbb Q^n \cap [0, 1]^n$ in $[0, 1]^n$.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for your answer. I guessed the answer was more or less like this, but I wanted to make sure. Every open subset in $T$ has type $U_1 \times U_2 \times \cdots \times U_n$. And there exists an element of a finite (cyclic, closed) subgroup of the circle in each $U_i$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461901/for-topological-torus-action-there-is-a-subcircle-whose-fixed-point-is-the-same#comment1198355_461901), it is not true that every open subset is a product, but what you doubtless meant, that every non-empty open subset contains a non-empty such product (around every point), is of course true.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, I mean basic open sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your revised argument in the post itself reduces the problem to showing that the union of circles (topological isomorphs of $S^1$) in $T$ is dense in $T$, and that our discussion in the comments ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1198334) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1198355)) establishes this latter.  Namely, the density of $\mathbb Q^n \cap [0, 1]^n$ in $[0, 1]^n$ implies that the set of finite-order elements of $T$ is dense in $T$.  Since every finite-order element of $T$ belongs to a circle, the result follows.

Comment: I've added a more general version of the problem here. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461934/the-union-of-1-dimensional-pro-tori-in-a-finite-dimensional-pro-torus-is-dense