# Is the union of 1-dimensional pro-tori in a finite dimensional pro-torus dense?

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

Is the union of 1-dimensional compact connected abelian subgroups in a finite dimensional compact connected abelian group dense?

Comment: Based on your other question [For topological torus action, there is a subcircle whose fixed point is the same as the torus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461901/for-topological-torus-action-there-is-a-subcircle-whose-fixed-point-is-the-same), you are specifically interested in the non-Lie case, since a compact, connected, commutative Lie group is a torus.  But then how do you define dimension?

Comment: The title of your post has now changed to refer to pro-tori (which I guess are projective limits of tori?), but the body has not.  I assume that the body is meant to ask the same question?

Comment: @LSpice I'm just curious about the question in the title. I'm trying to adapt the lemma for Lie groups to non-Lie groups. a finite dimensional pro-torus is the projective limit of tori which has the same dimension with pro-torus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G$ is a $n$-dimensional compact connected abelian group, then
there exists a compact totally disconnected normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such
that $G/N$ is a torus. The union of all closed circle subgroups of $G/N$
is dense in $G/N$. On the other hand, the family of one dimensional compact
connected abelian subgroups $H$ of $G$ is the family of inverse images $%
\varphi ^{-1}\left( T\right) $ of all closed circle subgroups $T$ under
natural homomorphism $\varphi :G\longrightarrow G/N$. Therefore, since $%
\varphi $ is open,  $\bigcup_{H<G}H=\bigcup_{T<G/N}\varphi ^{-1}\left(
T\right) $ is dense in $G$.